# Attempting to Undraw in my GUI Python Game

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm creating a Memory Matching game for a final project for my compsci class.

As of now, I have the cards all appear on the GUI window once you hit start game.
Once start game is hit, all the cards with their face value shows with the back of the card immediately. (So you never actually see the card fronts)

My reasoning for doing this is so that when you click on a card, I'll simply undraw the back card image instead of "Flipping" anything.

However, I keep getting errors, and when I don't get errors, it simply results in my program saying "Not Responding" and makes me have to restart the Shell.

Here are some little bits and pieces of my code which I think pertain to my issue:

```
  for firstcard in range(6):
            firstrow = self.deck.dealCard()
            randomsuite = firstrow.getSuite()
            randomrank = firstrow.getRank()
            #Real image with face value of card
            realCard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/"+ (randomsuite) + str(randomrank) +".gif")
            realCard.draw(win)
            #Red Back of card to cover image
            firstcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
            firstcard.draw(win)
            #pushes the card to the right a bit
            xpos += 100


while not Quitbutton.isClicked(p):
        #Start Game
        if StartGameButton.isClicked(p) and player == True:
            if first == True:
                Game.gameboard(win,150,125)
                firstcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
                first = False
                if StartGameButton.isClicked(p):
                    p = win.getMouse()
                    if firstcard.isClicked(p):
                        firstcard.undraw()
                        p = win.getMouse()
```

As of now you can see I have in my code `if firstcard.isClicked(p):`. However, this doesn't actually work because my isClicked function is a part of a Button Class and therefore, only works when dealing with Buttons and not images. So I'm not entirely sure what to do to select a single card and how to show that that card has been clicked and therefore should be undrawn

Comment: You shouldn't have to 'undraw' anything.  When you want the card face up, draw a face, when you want it face down, draw the back...

Comment: @davo36, makes sense, i see what you're saying and seems better than What i'm attempting. But I'm still stuck on how to determine when the card has been clicked. I can't just do a win.getMouse() function, because that would mean wherever you click will draw the card

Comment: Why don't you make the image a button

Comment: @Natecat, i was confused as to how to do that. last night I tried writing firstcard as a button, but then since `firstcard = Image(point(xpos, ypos),"playingcards"`, i get the error that Image is not a button. I dont know how to make the image itself a button first

Comment: OK, so what GUI are you using?  TKinter? Something else?

Normally with these kinds of frameworks, they are event driven, so you receive a mouse click, you see where that click took place, and take the appropriate action.